How do I prevent my tween from playing double?
I have a simple project where I'm making a card battling game. The battle sequence looks like this:
     repeat

        BattleClient.PlayerAttackTween()
        task.wait(battleSpeed)
        BattleClient.EnemyAttackTween()
        task.wait(battleSpeed)
        battleRound += 1

    until isInBattle.Value == false

The issue I'm having is that if the player starts another battle right after finishing one, this loop is still in the middle of  a task.wait() and has not yet gotten to the until check to break the loop, so the tweens play double during that second fight.
How do I prevent this from happening?
Edit: Video showcasing issue

I think you should use another true/false flag to crack this problem.

IDK the whole function/loop but try this algorithm :
local isBattleActive = false -- new binary flag

function StartBattle()
    if isBattleActive then return end -- battle active :do not start
    isBattleActive = true

    repeat
        BattleClient.PlayerAttackTween()
        task.wait(battleSpeed)
        BattleClient.EnemyAttackTween()
        task.wait(battleSpeed)
        battleRound += 1
    until isInBattle.Value == false
    
    isBattleActive = false -- battle over, reset flag
end

